# How to check a condition with nested relation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem while getting data when using whereHas.

```
Addons::with(['addons_details','group_addons.group_addon_details'])->when($id,function($query) use ($id){
            $query->whereHas('group_addons',function($query) use ($id){
                $query->where('group_id',$id);
            });
        })
        ->orderBy('id','desc')->get()
```

Using this query i will get addons model details which exist in group_addons. I want to get all rows in Addons model.

Comment: If you remove where has query then you will get all addons. When and Where has query filters the addons.

Comment: @gguney If i remove where has i got all group details.I want only one group details..Any other solution.?

Comment: You can't use whereHas and getting all the rows at the same time, that's contradictory

Comment: @user6085744 whereHas creates a condition. You can just use with. If you addons has group_addons it will appear in addons' group_details if it does not then nothing joins. I think you should check you relation. If you remove when and where has conditions it should work as expected.